# How am I able to count how many specific string values of a certain kind I have in my list / dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, text, text-based

Utter newb here with a slowly but surely growing bad reputation. I want to know how my dictionary value char['bag']['Iron Ingot'], or any 'Ingot' for that matter, can be counted without showing a TypeError: 'list indices must be integers or slices, not str.' Counter doesn't seem to work, as it doesn't address the fact I am dealing with a string, not an int, that I want to count. I want to count this string and output an integer value - the number of said string I possess in my list.

```
char = {'name' : 'Hero',
    'lv': 3,
    'xp': 0,
    'lvnext': 83,
    'gp' : 1225,
    'bag' : ["Bronze Bastard", "Iron Ingot"],
    'stats' : {'ATT': 111,
                'DEF': 1,
                'WIS': 1,
                'hp' : 100,
                'atk' : [5,22]}}



def blacksmith():
print("The Master Smith is a giant-like abomination of a demon.")
print("Smith: Bring me ingot, and gold piece, and I will bend the metal to your liking.")
print("[1 ingot per Claw/Claymore/Helm/Gauntlets/Boots, 2 ingots per Bastard/Chain-whip, 4 ingots per Full suit/Liquid coat]")
print("[X ingot(s)] ")
item = input("Assuming you have the ingot and coin, I can make anything forged from the Titanite anvil. (Correctly type the item you want forged.)")
if item == "Iron Claws" and char['bag'].count("Iron Ingot") >= 1 and char['gp'] >= 15:
    char['bag'].append(item)
    char['bag'] - char['bag']['Iron Ingot']
    char['gp'] = char['gp'] - 15
    char['stats']['atk'][:] = [x + 1 for x in char['stats']['atk']]
    print("{} has been added to your bottomless bag!".format(item))
    chapterOne()
```

Answer (score 0):

After trying your code, I found that the error occurred because of using this

```py
char['bag']['Iron Ingot']
```

The error occurred because you can only access to the element inside the list by using `int`. The type of `char['bag']` is `list` therefore, you couldn't do this.

To count the elements inside your list, you can simply use the `Counter`, to do this, you just have to import it like below

```py
import collections

# Make a Counter object
count_object = collections.Counter(char['bag'])

# Before printing out, convert it to dict
print(dict(count_object))
```

You can make some changes to make your function works!